# How to use Gradle Logger?

Tags: logging, gradle, spock

> import org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
>
> import org.gradle.api.logging.Logging

in my Spock test

> package com.example.dummies
>
> import org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
>
> import org.gradle.api.logging.Logging
>
> import spock.lang.Specification
>
> class DummyClassTest extends Specification {
>
> ```
> File dir = new File("C:/Users/results")
> DummyClass var
> Logger LOG 
>
> def setup() {
>     LOG = Logging.getLogger(DummyClassTest.class)
>     var= new DummyClass(dir)
> }
>
> def ' test'() {
>     LOG.info("--------------------------------------------------->HI")
>  expect:
>  var.gettDir() == dir
> } }
> ```

My test passes but when I write

> gradle test -i

But my message is not in the console output. What could be the problem?

Comment: Not sure if Gradle redirects logging that takes place in test JVMs. One thing worth trying is to turn on test logging for standard streams (`test.testLogging.showStandardStreams = true`).